# How to set Timestamp property for column in External Content Type?

Tags: external-content-type, crawl-external-content, incremental-crawl

I created External Content Type (.ect) in Visual Studio. It is based on Netweaver service. One of the columns called `LastChangeDate`.

I added this content type to SharePoint and configured crawl on that BCS source.

I want to be able to use that column as timestamp, for incremental crawl. I read in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2010/04/27/searching-external-data-in-sharepoint-2010-using-business-connectivity-services/#Modifying), that i need to set Timestamp property on that column. How can I do it? I cannot find this option in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Open SharePoint Designer and edit the operations of the ECT.

Select the field "LastChangeDate" and set the Timestamp property

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I was asking about Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

With help of [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg512147(v=office.14).aspx#ConfSPS_part2_Modifyingthe) (in section Changelog-Based Incremental Crawls), I was able to figure it out. I had to open the created .ect file in text editor and add a filter.

Inside method named: `ReadAllContactPerson`:

```
<Parameter Name="@PartnerChangeDate" Direction="In">
  <TypeDescriptor Name="PartnerChangeDate" DefaultDisplayName="PartnerChangeDate" 
                  TypeName="System.DateTime" CreatorField="true" 
                  AssociatedFilter="PartnerChangeDate">
    <Interpretation>
      <NormalizeDateTime LobDateTimeMode="UTC" />
    </Interpretation>
  </TypeDescriptor>
</Parameter>

   ...

    <FilterDescriptors>
        <FilterDescriptor Name="PartnerChangeDate" Type="Timestamp" />
    </FilterDescriptors>
```

Pay attention to:

- Add `AssociatedFilter` attribute to descriptor of the column with timestamp
- Create a `FilterDescriptor` for the above filter, give it type `Timestamp`